# Advanced (probably not?) MYSQL query select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Please see the below sample data:

```
'messages' table data:
id, date, user, seen
674, 1399430687, 2, 0
675, 1399430957, 2, 1399431766 
676, 1399431065, 1, 1399431766
677, 1399431723, 2, 1399431766   
678, 1399434322, 2, 0
679, 1399434330, 2, 0
```

I want to do a count of only the most recent non seen (seen=0) records to a particular user (user: 2) UP and ONLY UNTIL the next seen record (seen>0). So in the above case there are 3 unseen (seen=0) records to user (user: 2) but only 2 of them I am interested as the next 1 has some seen records in between it. So in the above scenario count of 2 would be returned (not the actual records).

Also if the most recent record to user (user: 2) is seen (seen>0) then count of 0 should be returned. I just can't get my head around how to do this in mysql, or how to really describe it.

This is all I can work out, but in the above scenario this will result in 3, not 2:

```
 SELECT COUNT( * ) 
 FROM  `messages` 
 WHERE seen = 0
 AND user = 2
 ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing you need to realize is that the data in your database is not 'ordered' in any particular way. when you select `WHERE seen = 0` the other 'seen' data is not retrieved at all.

Comment: very true, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the latest non-zero seen data, and then filter after that.

```
SELECT Count(id) FROM data WHERE user = 3 AND seen = 0
AND date > (
    SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE seen <> 0 AND user = 3
);
```

[here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8741d/27)

EDIT:
The previous code wouldn't return a correct answer if the user hadn't seen any records yet at all, this code fixes it by returning 0 instead of null.

Comment: LOL, had seen jsfiddle before, thanks for introducing me to sqlfiddle.com - hadn't heard of it before.
Also many thanks, that works a charm with my limited testing.  Can you explain (if you have time) the "date >" part. I understand why to use a subquery, but not this use of it with "date".

Comment: the value returned from the subquery is the largest date value that has been seen. So, we use that value filter by date, returning only any records that have a date larger than that and have not been seen yet.

Comment: I guess, to help you understand a bit further, we use the result of the query as a variable to filter date by. In order for that to work, the query needs to return one value (for example, after thinking about it, the query won't work if the user hasn't seen any messages at all yet, since the subquery will return null)

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Using sqlfiddle I tried the scenario you mention (won't work if the user hasn't seen any messages at all yet, since the subquery will return null) and I can see what you mean. It returns 0 instead of 5. Any workaround for this? As this will be a very common scenario.

Comment: I noticed another problem with this. I think you also need the user = 2 in the subquery.  Using my sample data (and change seen to 0 for the user 1 row) if you change the query to user 1, it returns 0 results, but it should return 1. as user 1 will have 1 unseen result amongst those unseen results of user 2.

    SELECT Count(id) FROM data WHERE user = 1 AND seen = 0
AND date > (
    SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE seen <> 0 AND user = 1
);

Comment: I've created a new question on this, as it has got a bit more advanced, raising a different problem.  If you have time it would be great if you could have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555294/sql-query-select-statemenet