# SQL query select statemenet

Tags: mysql, sql

**Please see fiddle:**

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de208/1**

So far I have the following SQL statement which I thought works fine, except now I have found one problem case.

```
 SELECT Count(id) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen = 0
 AND date > (SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen <> 0);
```

**Part A)**
In the above fiddle this works well, it produces a count of 2 - the most unseen posts. 
The problem is that the most recent unseen post has been deleted before it had been seen, so it will also remain unseen. So the next time there is data, and this query is executed it will be counted again. Where it should only be counted once.

**Part B)**
So by the time the next fiddle (with a couple of new rows added) is executed the result is a count of 3 unseen posts, when in fact it should be 2.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e750b/1

*I think* the problem would only occur if the most recent unseen posts (as in record 677  in Part A fiddle) are deleted post. So it would be good to only included deleted posts in the count, if they are the most recent unseen post(s), and not come before an unseen non-deleted post (as in record 677 in Part B fiddle).

I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what your asking.  I am going to interpret it as you saying you do not want to count a deleted post.  If that is the case can you add AND deleted <> 1 to the first where clause?

Comment: Hi Razs. No, we do want to count a deleted post, but only once. As a deleted post in most likely unseen (it was deleted before it was seen) it will never be seen, thus it could be counted twice theatrically - which we do not want to happen. But it does need to be counted once.

Comment: How is it being counted twice? There are 3 rows newer than the last seen post, and the result is 3. So each of them is being counted just once.

Comment: Do you mean it will be counted once today, and counted again tomorrow?

Comment: Maybe you should mark unseen deleted posts as seen after running the query the first time.

Comment: @barmar - The deleted post (record 677) is counted in the first fiddle - which is correct (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de208/1). But in the second fiddle after 2 new rows have been added the deleted post (record 677) is being counted again. I only need it to be counted if the deleted record is the most recents. See Joseph B's answer which is an improvement on my provided SQL statement that half fixes this problem.

Comment: I still can't figure out the application logic you're trying to implement. Why are deleted posts counted differently depending on whether they're the most recent or not?

Answer (score 0):

The recount problem could happen with any post that remains unseen by the time the query runs again (whether it's deleted or not), so I think you need to keep track of the last time the query was run and only count new entries

```
SELECT Count(id) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen = 0
AND date > (SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen <> 0)
AND date > last_count_date
```

> I think the problem would only occur if the most recent unseen posts
>   (as in record 677 in Part A fiddle) are deleted post. So it would be
>   good to only included deleted posts in the count, if they are the most
>   recent unseen post(s), and not come before an unseen non-deleted post
>   (as in record 677 in Part B fiddle).

I'm not sure that's true. Suppose the following 2 rows are added between running count queries: deleted unseen followed by unseen. In this case the deleted unseen post is not the most recent one but should still be included in the count.

Comment: thanks for your time/input. I am not sure where last_count_date comes from in your query. There is no such field.  Joseph B's answer almost hits the nail on the head, except in this scenario: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/874f3/1.

Comment: last_count_date is a new piece of information that you need to store every time you run the query (initialize it at 0), it represents the date the query was previously run. I don't believe it's possible to avoid 'recounts' without storing some information on what has already been counted for the reasons mentioned in my post.

Comment: Thanks.I believe it is possible to avoid recounts as long as you define the scenario when the deleted messages are to be counted (which is when they are the most recent records) as per Joseph B's solution.The second time the count is done,there is a query the marks the previous unseen (but non deleted) posts as seen, as they are being displayed to the user.As deleted posts arent display this doesnt occur for them.This happens after this query is executed.so any nondeleted posts that are unseen now will be marked seen once the query executes again.sorry,I should have better explained it

Comment: Actually @FuzzyTree - i have played with several other scenarios now, and I think you are right. It would be best to leave my existing query as it is, and then mark a deleted post seen at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your logic to

> only included deleted posts in the count, if they are the most recent
>   unseen post(s)

would work perfectly. I modified the original query and added an additional condition to perform this check, as below.

```
SELECT Count(id) 
FROM data 
WHERE user = 2 
AND seen = 0
AND date > (SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen <> 0)
AND (deleted = 0
     OR (date = (SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen = 0)));
```

So, either deleted must be 0 or if it is 1 (deleted), then its date value must equal to the latest data of unseen posts.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e750b/8)

Comment: Thanks, I've been playing with this, and been trying to understand the logic and been getting nowhere :)  I noticed a problem when >1 of the most recent posts are marked at deleted it only counts one of them and stops there. eg. this fiddle should return 3. 2 most recent posts are deleted and 1 slightly older unseen non-deleted post.

Comment: changing the OR part of the query to date <= (SELECT coalesce(MAX(date),0) FROM data WHERE user = 2 AND seen = 0) seems to work in my very limited test. but not really understanding it, so it may not be the solution.

Comment: ehh, not it isn't the fix, in this fiddle only 1 should be returned (as a deleted post is not the most recent unseen post) but 2 is returned (including the deleted post): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/874f3/1